# How to handle allegedly misleading/incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a review where the a new user gave an answer, to which an anonymous user has proposed an edit claiming that the answer is plainly incorrect. To make the matters worse, neither of them had any references to back up the claims. As I had no idea about the sport, I could not take a stand on either way. Seeing as Sports.SE is growing, it would be naive to think that users with mod privileges know every conceivable detail of every sport. So here's my question, how does one handle such cases?

For the sake of example I will do a c/p of the answer and the proposed edit:

> Let's say there's a runner on 3rd with less than 2 outs. The game is tied and it's the bottom of the last inning. A deep flyball is hit towards the RF or LF line. If the fielder catches the ball, he'll have no chance to throw the runner out at the plate. If the umpire signals foul first, the fielder can let it drop, since the play will be dead and the runner can't advance. In this situation, it's clearly important for the fielder to know whether it's fair or foul before he decides whether to catch the ball or not.
>
> Edit: I cannot improve this answer as it is incorrect. A fly ball is neither fair nor foul until it lands past first or third base, is touched by a player or leaves the playing field over a wall. No umpire will ever call a ball fair or foul while it is in the air.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have rejected the edit as a radical change; edits should not be used to add an entire paragraph explaining why the rest of the answer is wrong.

Nor should wrong answers be deleted; that's what voting is for. In fact, one of the three predefined reasons for declining a flag is "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Comment: ok, good to know..